# Issues Building Datatable Within ng-bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, angular, datatable, modal-dialog, ng-bootstrap

I have an Angular 7.2.15 project that I have installed ng-bootstrap (https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples) on with great success until now when I realize I need to change the contents of the modal dialog.

The dialog will simply display the result of an API call which I know is coming back fine from Chrome Network views, essentially for each record that comes back, we need to display the "name" attribute in the datatable as a link (eventually, that link will load a saved query by its name) and an icon to delete it.

Here are the two important snippets from the search-bar.component.html in question:

```
<ng-template #contentOpen let-modal>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">Open Query</h4>   
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button> 
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    Select from the following list of saved queries:
    <table #dataTable class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr class="table-header">
    <td class="max-width-80">Search Name</td>
    <td class="max-width-20">Delete</td>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="table-body">
    </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</ng-template>

...

  <div class="col-md-1">
    <button class="SearchGrayButton" (click)="openModal(contentOpen)">Open Search <span class="fa fa-folder-open-o"></span></button>
  </div>
```

Then, in our search-bar.component.ts - we successfully get the SearchHistory from our webservice from the filteringService, but rendering the results poses the issue. If I take the datatable *out* from the ng-template #contentOpen section above, it will render the datatable fine (albeit not in the modal as we would like it to be). So within the modal, it does not render at all, but outside of it, the table will render without issue.

```
  openModal(content) {
    this.GetSearchHistory();

    this.modalService.open(content, {ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title'}).result.then((result) => {
      this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
    }, (reason) => {
      this.closeResult = `Dismissed`;
    });
  }

    /* Obtains all of the search history for a user and renders table in
    the modal to display them */
    GetSearchHistory() {
      this.filteringService.getSearchHistory().subscribe(
        resp => {
          console.log(resp, 'res');
          let r: WebServiceResponse;
          r = resp as WebServiceResponse;
          this.searchHistory = r.data;
          this.buildTableForSearchHistory();
      },
        error => { console.log(error, 'error'); }
      );
    }

  buildTableForSearchHistory() {
    const options = {
      sDom: 't',
      renderer: 'bootstrap',
      destroy: true,
      data: this.searchHistory,
      columns: [
        { data: 'name',
          className: 'dt-center max-width-10'
        }
      ],
      order: [0, 'desc'],
      createdRow( row, data, dataIndex ) {
      },
      drawCallback: () => {
      }
    };
    this.dataTable = $(this.table.nativeElement);
    this.dataTable.DataTable(options);
  }
```

As a test, I also set up a mock "refresh" button of sorts within the modal that would trigger the `getSearchHistory()` we see above and build the table after we know the modal is in focus, and this also does not resolve the issue. The console complains about the following line, which makes sense as I think it's having trouble finding the table in question to render to:

`this.dataTable = $(this.table.nativeElement);`

I don't know if it's needed beyond context especially for how simple it is, but a sample of the web service's JSON response in question:

```
{"status":null,"code":null,"messages":[],"data":[{"id":1,"userId":null,"name":"manual test name","queryText":null,"filtersJson":null},{"id":2,"userId":null,"name":"testname","queryText":null,"filtersJson":null},{"id":3,"userId":null,"name":"testname","queryText":null,"filtersJson":null}]}
```

Also noteworthy is we don't necessarily have to use DataTables here, as requirements really only are to display all the names as links and perhaps have the queryText and filtersJson as metadata since we'll need them for later. I just thought it might be a "nice to have" if we allow them to sort the results.

Does anyone have any thoughts or ways to help resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realized binding in this manner resolves it since there was no need for the DataTables usage:

```
  <div class="modal-body">
    Select from the following list of saved queries:
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let s of searchHistory">{{s.name}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```